# Is there a syntax them for Visual Studio 2019 that's similar to VSCode dark+ theme?

Tags: visual-studio, colors, themes

I'm very used to using Visual Studio Code, and admire the dark+ theme that comes with it standard. I want to use the Visual Studio IDE for projects, and would like to use the exact same or similar theme within the IDE. However, I can't find the syntax them for VS IDE 2019, and only find images of the application with the syntax theme inside. Could someone please show me where I can find or download the syntax theme?

Comment: There's a whole load of VS2019 themes [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.ColorThemesforVisualStudio) - if the in-built "Dark" theme (plus some customization) isn't enough.